# Route input from the Mac to iPhone via headphonejack

Tags: macos, audio, iphone

I need to route the audio output from my mac onto my iPhone through the headphone jack. I have a cable which has the headphone jack on both the ends. Will it be possible to route the audio through this cable. If not, what kind of cable will I need and is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The headphone jack on the iPhone is output only, not input.  To load audio input into your iPhone, you will need to connect your iPhone to a computer that has iTunes running.  Your mac should have iTunes by default.

Instead of trying to route the audio directly through headphone jacks, use a tool like Audacity to capture the audio.  Then load the audio file into iTunes and migrate that onto your iPhone.

Comment: Actually, this is not entirely correct.  The headphone jack is actually a combination headphone/microphone jack.  It has microphone input and headphone output.

Comment: Technically yes, but it's mono only. And it wouldn't echo the sound out the speaker that way. I think he wants to use his iPhone as a computer speaker (although I have no idea why you'd want to do that).

Comment: @WesSayeed  I am trying to play an audio which can then be processed in the iPhone. I do not want to listen to the audio multiple times so I want to know if I can route it from headphone jack of my Mac to the headphone jack of my Phone. The cable as i mentioned contains the 3mm headphone jack point on both sides

Comment: Is there a way to reconfigure the headphone jack's route via AVAudioSession?